# AS3 - How to completely remove 1 row of a 2D array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have a simple 2D array with multiple rows.  I want to be able to completely delete a row - not just make it blank/empty.

I have a button that removes the selected row.  I've tried the following methods, but all of them leave an empty row in the array, as opposed to completely removing the row. (in this example the first row, but it needs to work on any row selected).

```
array[0] = [];
array[0].splice();
array[0].length = 0;
array[0].splice(0);
array[0] = null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.splice()` is the method you need.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var grid:Array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

        public function Main() 
        {
            trace(this.grid); // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

            grid.splice(0, 1);

            trace(this.grid); // 4,5,6,7,8,9
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you!  `grid.splice(0, 1);` did the trick.  I researched splice a bit more and realize now why and how this works.